# How to generate set of specific string values with maximum of 6 digits?

Tags: python

I am working on a project in Python 3 where I need to create a sequence without adding digits. The numbers should be a string saved in a set, since it's faster than a list and they're all unique values.

I.e., I need something like:

#### Output

```
000001
000002
000003
...
000010
000011
...
000100
//and so on
```

#### Code

```
def build_sequence():
    seq = set()
    // logic here
    return seq
```

I have no idea how to solve this issue. It would be great if someone could put me in the right direction.

Comment: Your goal is not clear. What do you mean by "create a sequence without adding digits"? What restrictions are there on the numbers in the sequence? Would `list(range(m, n))` suffice? Is the "output" to be printed or returned? And so on.

Comment: The maximum amount of digits need to be 6 at all time

Comment: You should proabably go for a yield function where values are returned "on the fly".

Comment: python numbers are just numbers, so you can't keep 0's at the beginning

Comment: You can though, if you use numeric strings

Comment: @M.Douglas see my answer

Comment: Thanks, that helps ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

But the first will be to get the lower and upper limit of the desired sequence, from the question lets assume 0 to hundred. A simple for loop should do the trick

```
for i in range(1,100):
    print(i)
```

This should print 1 to 100 as

> 1 2 3 .... 100

But we want a sequence, there are many pythonic approach to this,
A simple one is format

```
format(1, "06") 
'000001'
```

Put this in loop.

In python 3.6, we have f-strings

```
temp_var = 19
f'{temp_var:06}'
```

There are lots of other methods as well, google and python docs are a great start

Comment: This what the solution I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of vague, but from what I can guess you want a function to generate from `000000` to `999999`.

```
def build_sequence():
    for i in range(1000000):
        yield "%.6d" % i
```

You can then iterate through each string using

```
for i in build_sequence():
    print(i)
```

where `i` is the string

Comment: your build sequence should accept the variable 1000000 and probably a lower bound too.

Comment: @AntonvBR honestly the question is so vague that I wasn't sure what they wanted

Comment: @DanielGee True, but hard-coding values isn't even good in examples